# How come there are two forms to the coefficient of determination?

Tags: r-squared, curve-fitting

On Wikipedia, it says:
$$
R^{2}= 1-{\sum _{i}(y_{i}-f_{i})^{2} \over \sum _{i}(y_{i}-{\bar {y}})^{2}}
$$
However, on other sites, R is defined as the following:
$$
R = { n({\sum xy})-({\sum x})({\sum y})\over {\sqrt {(n{{\sum(x^2)-({\sum x})^2})(n{{\sum(y^2)-({\sum y})^2})}}}}}
$$
and $R^2 = R \times R$

Am I missing something? In which circumstance am I supposed to use one versus the other?

(I'm trying to find $R^2$ for a polynomial regression)

Comment: Simple answer: always use the first one.

Comment: The R-squared (R2) value can be calculated as "R2 = 1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)", and can be interpreted as the amount of variance in the data that is explained by your model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The more general expression is your first one: $R^{2}= 1-{\sum _{i}(y_{i}-f_{i})^{2} \over \sum _{i}(y_{i}-{\bar {y}})^{2}}$
- Your second one is equivalent in the special case of simple linear regression (one right hand side variable and an intercept), that is:
  $$y_i = a + b x_i + \epsilon_i$$
  In this special case, [$R^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#As_squared_correlation_coefficient) is given by the square of the sample correlation coefficient between  $Y$ and $X$, and $R$ as defined above is the [sample correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) between $Y$ and $X$. (The fitted values are given by $f_i = a + bx_i$.)

#### More detailed algebra showing $R$ is the sample correlation coefficient

Let $\mu_x = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i$ be the sample mean. Let's unpack your 2nd expression:
\begin{align*}
R &= \frac{ n\left({\sum xy}\right)-\left({\sum x}\right)\left({\sum y}\right)}{\sqrt{\left(n \sum x^2 - \left(  \sum x\right)^2 \right)\left(n \sum y^2 - \left( \sum y\right)^2 \right)}} \\
&= \frac{ \frac{1}{n}\sum xy - \mu_x \mu_y}{\sqrt{\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum x^2 - \mu^2_x \right) \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum y^2 - \mu^2_y \right) }} \\
&= \frac{ \frac{1}{n}\sum (x - \mu_x)(y- \mu_y)}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum \left( x - \mu_x \right)^2  \frac{1}{n}\sum   (y - \mu_y)^2  }}
\end{align*}

Comment: Is y=a+bx+cx^2 also considered simple linear regression? Or is the x^2 considered a second right side variable?

Comment: @ShellyCao $x^2$ is another right hand side variable. $y_i=b_0+b_1x_i+b_2x_i^2+\epsilon_i$ is a perfectly fine model to estimate with ordinary least squares, but you have to use the more general formulas.

Comment: @ShellyCao Don't worry about this comment, but FYI, depending an author's convention, $x^2$ would be a 2rd or 3rd right hand side variable. The way you get to three is you say the data is $(1, x_i, x_i^2)$, that is, you call the intercept a variable that's always one. $y_i = b_0 \cdot 1 + b_1 \cdot x_i + \ldots$. This ends up making some formulas nicer. (eg. you can write the OLS estimator as $\mathbf{b} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$ in matrix algebra.